# Is there any thing in rails that helps us to know what and all actions are travelled that a route request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have  a huge rails code many routes and i see the console that says for the route home/index

Processing by `HomeController#index` as HTML
but i don't even see with binding.pry that the route hit but i get 200OK response in my terminal i see that there are many filters  being called but i don't know which filter is being called as there are 100's of modules being include.

Is there a formula that guides us telling which page the action has traversed through which module only in the project but not to the internal rails code like traversing inside the rails gem and all.

I get a very white screen on chrome for localhost:3000/ where there is no layout being loaded. So i need to backtrace to what actions has my route hit and what and all callbacks are involved in performing that action.

Its waste of time with binding.pry putting at lots of places.

```
I, [2019-11-07T13:41:06.046091 #22077]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-11-07 13:41:06 +0530

[DEPRECATION] `strip_attributes!` is deprecated.  Please use `strip_attributes` (non-bang method) instead.

[DEPRECATION] `strip_attributes!` is deprecated.  Please use `strip_attributes` (non-bang method) instead.

W, [2019-11-07T13:41:07.190395 #22077]  WARN -- : Creating scope :track_allowed. Overwriting existing method CustomFieldDefinition.track_allowed.

W, [2019-11-07T13:41:07.190553 #22077]  WARN -- : Creating scope :document_allowed. Overwriting existing method CustomFieldDefinition.document_allowed.

W, [2019-11-07T13:41:07.190643 #22077]  WARN -- : Creating scope :image_allowed. Overwriting existing method CustomFieldDefinition.image_allowed.
W, [2019-11-07T13:41:07.190724 #22077]  WARN -- : Creating scope :video_allowed. Overwriting existing method CustomFieldDefinition.video_allowed.

[DEPRECATION] `strip_attributes!` is deprecated.  Please use `strip_attributes` (non-bang method) instead.
[DEPRECATION] `strip_attributes!` is deprecated.  Please use `strip_attributes` (non-bang method) instead.
W, [2019-11-07T13:41:07.325206 #22077]  WARN -- : Creating scope :by_ids. Overwriting existing method MediaFormat.by_ids.
I, [2019-11-07T13:41:07.334538 #22077]  INFO -- : Processing by HomeController#index as HTML

D, [2019-11-07T13:41:07.336651 #22077] DEBUG -- :   Track Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "tracks".* FROM "tracks" WHERE (tracks.purged_at IS NULL)
I, [2019-11-07T13:41:07.339979 #22077]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 2.3ms | Path: http://localhost:3000/)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are assuming that the `/` (root path) should hit `HomeController#index` I think you should check your routes.

A specific url always can only hit one action. In this case your log tells us it is processed by the `MainController#home` method.

Check your routes (in `config/routes.rb`) and check your `root` definition.
It should be

```
 root to: 'home#index'
```

(and also check if there are multiple occurrences)

Comment: i know that the routes are specific if i put binding.pry to my main controller home action the thing is it doesnot stop their due to the different callbacks and filters that needed to be taken but the callbacks do exist in various modules which are 25 in quantity i cannot put binding.pry at every place and check and do a trail and error .

Comment: In your question you refer to `HomeController#index`, your logging hits `MainController#home` and now you write `main controller home action`, does this mean: that your question was wrong? That you fixed and added `binding.pry` to the correct controller and it still does not stop on the debugger?

Comment: yes sorry fro that its actully Home Controller# index itself but  can i trace what and all files and actions are being called in the that particular route without debugger making a trail and error effect

Comment: i checked the routes its fine root to: 'home#index' and the point at which i'm stuck was the layout was not rendering i finally tried to fix my application with some proc blocks and removing before filters where the error is being caused